# How to add Equal Spacing and equal width for button in iOS Auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Am new to Auto layout constraints in Xcode. I have one Bottom View like `UITabBar` with 6 `UIButtons`. Without constraints I aligned those buttons with 5 space padding with each buttons and each buttons has 50 width. 
Now,I am trying to make it by using Auto layout to support all Screen sizes.

> In Storyboard constrains I set equal width for 6 buttons and I made 60
>   space between each buttons. I set first button 0 to leading space and
>   I set the last button 0 to tail constraints.

I want the `buttons with equal width and flexible spaces` between views in all device sizes.

Can anyone pleas help me? Looking for the help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 62, accepted):

check this image and made your constraints like below...

[image]

**RESULT:-** preview in different sizes

[image]

---

**With Stackview** (For iOS 9.0 and above)

[image]

> NOTE: If you have to make app for iOS 9 and later then `UIStackView` is another option for you

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need one clarification. Have you added 5 views in between the buttons (1-6) is it?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 great answer! i have a question why when using stackview the views don't obtain perfect squares? i posted this question but no answer to it yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540494/using-stackview-to-create-matrix-of-square-views-ios

Comment: Perfect solution 100 Points for you

Comment: there is a spacing option for the UIstackView, why aren't using that? and you are adding extra views between the buttons?

Comment: @KarimIhab Its just simple demonstrate if u dont want to use sizeclass with seperate spacing .. this will adjust spacing according to views

Answer (score 11):

With iOS 9 and Xcode 7, you can now have the expected result with `UIStackView` and only 3 or 4 auto layout constraints.

The following step by step uses Storyboard.

1. Create 6 `UIButton`s and 5 `UIView`s. Align them horizontally. Give some color to your views.

[image]

2. Select all your views and buttons and click on the `Stack` button. You will have all your buttons and colored views aligned in a `UIStackView`.

[image]

3. Select your stack view, go to the `Utilities` panel and select the `Attributes Inspector` item. There, click on the `Distribution` button and select "Fill Equally".

[image]

4. For now, your stack view's height relies on your buttons intrinsic content size. If you're fine with it, you can go to step 5. However, if needed, you can give your stack view a height constraint. Select your stack view, click on the `Pin` button, check the `Height` button, add the required value and click on the `Add 1 Constraint` button.

[image]

As an alternative, If you want each element of your stack view to have its height matching its width, select the first button of your stack view, click on the `Pin` button, select `Aspect Ratio` and click on the `Add 1 Constraint` button.

[image]

You can check that your aspect ratio constraint is correct in your `Document outline` (left panel) and, if you need, you can change it with a different constraint in the `Attribute inspector` (right panel).

[image]

5. Now, it's time to give some external constraints to your stack view. Select your stack view. Click on the `pin` button, make sure the `Constrain to margin` button is not select and set leading, trailing and bottom constraints to zero. Make sure that the bottom constraint is related to your view controller's view. Then, change the `Update Frames` button to "All Frames in Container". You can now click on the `Add 3 Constraints` button.

[image]

Your stack view is now set.

[image]

Further remark:

If you don't need your colored views width to match your buttons width, you can build a stack view with only `UIButtons` and simply add spacing to your stack view in the `Attribute inspector`. However, you will have to find a way to add a background color behind your stack view. Apple states about it in the [UIKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/):

> The UIStackView is a nonrendering subclass of UIView. It does not
>   provide any user interface of its own. Instead, it just manages the
>   position and size of its arranged views. As a result, some properties
>   (like backgroundColor) have no affect on the stack view.

---

I've build a Xcode project with 4 different stack views:

- one with colored views and relying on the embedded `UIButton`s intrinsic content size for its height,
- one with colored views and with a `UIButton` "equal width and height" constraint,
- one with colored views and with its own height constraint,
- one without colored views but with spacing and embedded inside a colored view.

You can find this project on this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/imanoupetit/Stack).

Comment: will they maintain a perfect squares sir?

Answer (score 1):

iOS 9 has a new UIKit class called UIStackView. It is very helpful in stacking up views horizontally or vertically, like the way you want. You should check out this tutorial: [Raywenderlich: UIStackView Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views)

Comment: but also note that...its only available if your app supports minimum iOS9

Comment: There's a working iOS 7+ port that's pretty good. https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView  @EICaptain

Answer (score 0):

Select all the buttons and in Xcode’s Pin menu

1. Create a horizontal constraint from the top left view to the top right view by selecting the red line to the selected view’s right side nearest neighbor
2. Create a horizontal constraint from the top right view to the top left view by selecting the red line to the selected view’s left side nearest neighbor
3. Create a vertical constraint from the top view by selecting the red line to the selected view’s top side nearest neighbor
4. Select checkbox near to Height, Equal Widths and click on "*Add 22 Constraints*"

Answer (score 0):

Spacer views should no longer be necessary unless you need space between borders.

You can create a StackView with equal spacing which will dynamically adjust the space between your stack views to use up all available space without altering the size of your subviews.

Interface builder can be a bit misleading here. the value you put in for spacing is the minimum spacing required not what the actual spacing will be.
[image: StackView Configuration Screenshot]

The StackView will handle your spacing, making the size of your buttons equal you can use regular constraints for.