# How to create storyboard layout multiple views within header view iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, autolayout

I have created header `UIView` on `storyboard` view controller, now I need to create 4 views like below colored image Into that `UIview` base view. It should show for all devices. Need to adjust auto layout using `iOS`.

[image]

Comment: YES! Exactly but Its should show for all devices@EI Captain

Comment: ok...you can check this and try using this links...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620409/need-assistance-setting-two-buttons-of-equal-width-side-by-side-autolayout/29620794#29620794  or check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862142/how-to-add-equal-spacing-and-equal-widht-for-button-in-ios-auto-layout/32862693#32862693  ...tell me if you want more help

Comment: Awesome help. Mr.EI Captain. Thank you so much! Btw when U l update?:)

Comment: i think you need to set proportional width of all four views to 0.25 related to HeaderView.

Comment: Sorry I cant get you!@MaheshDhapa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First set constraints to header view. Select header view and apply following constraints:

- Leading, top, trailing space and Height = 80 (for example)

Once you apply constraints to header view then select all buttons at once :

[image]

Hope this can help

Comment: great..I am trying plz give me 5 min!@Irfan

Comment: When adding uiview to header view make sure they don't overlap each other. First make them resize like the buttons here.

Comment: Sure plz give me a min!I am trying!

Comment: Thanks. And glad it helped you

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

Now IOS 9 realse new feature `stackview` .

U can drag the `stackview` into your header view and add `uiviews` into it.

You can also change `stackview`'s properties based on your project..