# Can anyone put a row of buttons in xcode like the picture?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, row

Can anyone put a row of buttons in Xcode like in the picture?
I want to put images as buttons!

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368025/how-to-create-storyboard-layout-multiple-views-within-header-view-ios/34368263#34368263  ... check

Comment: you can add images on UIButton, it is possible

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions of you question

1. You should use custom segment controller for that type of button you can use [STSegmentedControl](https://github.com/SkyTrix/STSegmentedControl) .
2. And obviously you can add image on UIButton but if you want to exactly like this than use UIButtons in StackView and change images of UIButons. StackView will help you to arrange UIButtons.

Hope it will help you..

Thanks