# Xcode 7 - Constraints - equal spacing between buttons

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to get horizontal equal spacing between 11 buttons, I have tried with the IB but I cannot get the buttons to space equally in different screen sizes. Also I want to increase the size of the buttons and keep the ratio of each button on bigger screen.

3.5-inch
[image]

5.5-inch
[image]

I have been trying with all different constraints setup but I cannot get it right. Is this Possible to achieve and if yes How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Equal Spacing and equal width for button in iOS Auto layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862142/how-to-add-equal-spacing-and-equal-width-for-button-in-ios-auto-layout)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To layout 11 buttons equally spaced, put 10 spacer views between them:

[image: 11 buttons]

---

Set the following constraints:

1. Set a **Leading Space to Container View Margin** constraint between the leftmost button and the left margin.
2. Set a **Trailing Space to Container View Margin** constraint between the rightmost button and the right margin.
3. Pin all of the buttons and spacer views to their left and right neighbors.  The *constant* should be 0.
4. Set the height of all of the spacer views (to something like `64`).
5. Set an **Equal Widths** constraint between the leftmost button and the top level view.  Change the *multiplier* to `1:18`.  This will allow the button size to grow on bigger screens.
6. Select all 11 buttons (by holding down <kbd>shift</kbd> and click on the 11 buttons.  Choose **Equal Widths** and **Aspect Ratio**.  Make the **Aspect Ratio** *constant* `1` for square buttons.
7. Select all 10 spacer views and set **Equal Widths**.
8. Set a **Vertical Spacing to Top Layout Guide** constraint between the leftmost button and the top margin.
9. Select all 11 buttons and 10 spacer views and select **Align Vertical Centers**.
10. Select all 10 spacer views and set their *hidden* property in the *Attributes Inspector*.

---

#### On the iPhone 4S (3.5 inch):

[image: iPhone 4S Simulator]

---

#### On the iPhone 6S Plus (5.5 inch):

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much, very nice approach.

Answer (score 8):

Use a horizontal `UIStackView` and set it to "fill equally"

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for a solution working on 8.0 as well

Comment: also using stack view the minimum width and height is 30px;

Comment: @SNos Check out [`FDStackView`](https://github.com/forkingdog/FDStackView).