# iOS equally spacing views

Tags: ios, storyboard

[image]
Hi, Why is this come out this way on iPad 2 air?? I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32862693/2844934).

I want the white placeholders to be smaller in width.

Comment: So what you want is left aligned labels?

Comment: Are you using StackView or just constraints? Show us your code.

Comment: You followed that, but not quite, in the left image you don't have views between this colour views.

Comment: you can use stack view and can set the space between the contents. It will provide you the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all views to be equally spaced, use horizontal `UIStackView` and set the spacing property to `equal`.

Or if you want to manually do this via constraints, you have to have to set your views' width **proportional** to the `device/superView's` width.

For example, if your iPhone/iPad width is `320`, if you want `4` views to be equally spaced, divide the **screen width** by the **number of views** while setting equal width constraint to the views:

```
320 / 4 = 80 (Width of each view)
```

**Do the below steps for all your required views/buttons: (I am using buttons for example purpose)**

This is where we begin:
[image: Beginning]

**Step1:** 
Set `Top` and `Leading` constraints of your `Button1` to its superview like this: [image: Top and Leading Constraints]

**Step 2:** 
Make your button `Equal Width` and `Equal Height` of its superview.
[image: Make button equal width and height of its superview]

**Step 3:**
Now your button would apparently be of same size as your super view. Here comes the fun and easy part. Make your button's width 1/4th (If you have 6 views that needs to be equally spaced, make it 1/6) of your superview's width by editing the constraint.
[image: Set width multiplier to 1/4]

**Step 4:**
Apply constraints from previous steps to all the views/buttons and update frames to see the change.

[image: Final output]

**These are the constraints for the first button for your reference:** 
[image: Total constraints for the button]

Comment: First, i have tried it with stackview but I could not adjust its height and other values sometimes on storyboard. I do not know why. And it stretched too much on bigger device.

Comment: I will check this tonight... your way of doing it seems interesting. It makes sense but I could not think of it lol... I have one more question. Is there a way to make its height proportional to its width? I have tried this with stackview and on the bigger size device, the icons stretched too much. I am not sure if your method handles it.

Comment: There is no way of making height proportional to width via constraints in IB as such. But there is a possibility to do that using custom `NSLayoutConstraint` subclass with `@IBInspectable` property.