# Arrange horizontal space between items in a bar using autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I'm currently has a View like this, how can I setup the constraint to display the items equally like the Iphone 7 review in all size of screen?. I've tried so many constraint including stackView but no use. Thank you very much and have good day ahead.

[image]

Comment: You may want to use stackview for that

Comment: I've tried, but its seem not good. the Done button still missing apart and i also wanna know another solutions.

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen you need bottom icons to be equally aligned?Try giving equal width and height constraint if they have one else better option stack view.

Comment: What constraints have you set up?  Are these in a UIToolbar or just 5 UIButtons in a containing view?

Comment: Refer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862142/how-to-add-equal-spacing-and-equal-width-for-button-in-ios-auto-layout

Comment: @Paulw11 it just  5 UIButtons in a container View

Comment: So what constraints have you set up?

Comment: Actually i'm not setting any constraint, after tried various ways

Comment: If you don't want to use a stack view then you will either need to use spacer `UIView`s between each button (You can do this in interface builder) or use a `UILayoutGuide` (You can only do this programatically).

Answer (score 0):

You can use five view in the black view:

[image]

Constraint for first view:

- leading space to superview : 0
- Bottom and top space to superview : 0
- trailing space to second view  : 0

Constraint for second, third and fourth view:

- leading space to left view : 0
- Bottom and top space to superview : 0
- trailing space to right view  : 0
- equal with and equal height with first view

Constraint for last(5th) view:

- leading space to left view (4th) : 0
- Bottom and top space to superview : 0
- trailing space to superview  : 0
- equal with and equal height with first view

Then insert your button or element in these view with their constraint (eg. horizontal center / vertical center)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UIToolbar` which features a `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` item that you can place in between your 5 regular items.

In Obj-C code you'd do something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

    UIBarButtonItem* spaceItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                                target:self
                                                                                action:nil];

    ... create other items ...

    self.toolbarItems = @[ item1, spaceItem1, item2, spaceItem2, ... ];

    ...
}
```